# What does the Yang-Mills flow and the Yang-Mills QFT tell about each other?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, yang-mills-theory

What are some known examples of what the Yang-Mills Quantum Field Theory can tell about solutions to Yang-Mills heat equation?
In general, what are some known examples of what the QFT of a Lagrangian functional can say about solutions to the gradient flow of a Lagrangian functional?  (Beyond, of course, the obvious: that the static solutions to the flow are the solutions to the Euler-Lagrange equations, and thus the stationary points of the action.)

More specifically, what can a QFT say about solutions to non-linear versions of the heat and bioheat equations?

Comment: The question seems to me impossibly broad. A reasonable answer would have to be a treatise on the subject!

Comment: @Igor Khavkine,  I've edited the problem to be a little more specific.  It still may be too broad.